# How to have a full screen div with top and bottom sticky navbars

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to have the following style layout

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Top Sticky Nav                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--+
|                                                        |S |
|                                                        |C |
| Div                                                    |R |
|                                                        |O |
|                                                        |L |
|                                                        |L |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--+
| Bottom Sticky Nav                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to use Bootstrap 4 nav bars that are stuck to the top and bottom of the page.  Sandwiched in-between is a div with my content that will automatically show a scroll bar if the divs content is larger than the area between the two Navs.  The scrollbar should only show on the div and not be covered by either of the navs.

This seems simple to me but every solution I have tried seems to be a bit flaky when moving between full screen, partial screen and mobile sizes.

Fyi the contents of the div will be a Bootstrap4 form.

Does anyone have any tips or examples for something similar?

I should also mention the div needs move down when the navbar is compressed on a mobile device and the hamburger mention is shown and opened.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yep.  as I mentioned I have tried a bunch of different things.I'm sure it's a very simple solution that I'm missing

Comment: again not quite what I'm after.  The scrollbar is over the entire page and the footer starts to disappear if you size the height small enough to show the scrollbar

Comment: Demonstrate what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you have some [position classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-top) like `.fixed-top`, this will set the element on the top of the viewport edge to edge and `.fixed-bottom` will do the same but on the bottom.

Your code should look like this:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: Aqua;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-top red">Fixed top</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-12 blue">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a</div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-bottom red">Bottom</div>
```

As you can see I added a height for the top fixed element because we need to add a margin on the container with the same amount of pixels like the top height, so the content doesn't start under the top element, same with the bottom element but instead of `margin-top`, we use `margin-bottom`.

I have created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPGXKM) for you.

Answer (score 0):

BS4 layout

```
<div class="fixed-top">
<!-- navbar or any thing you can add ad top div -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

</nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  class container or container-fluid or section ... what ever you want 
</div>

<div class="fixed-bottom">
<!-- navbar or any thing you can add ad bottom div -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">

</nav>
</div>
```